# forEach in mongoDB array not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb model like:

```
Data = {
   dataID: String,
   myarray:[]
}
```

I need to iterate through **myarray**

In my API I am writing like this

```
Data.findOne({dataID: '1234567890'}, function(err, data){
   data.myarray.forEach(function(toMatch, index){
       data.myarray[index].key = value;
   });

   data.save(function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        return res.status(200).send(data)
   })
});
```

but **data** is not getting saved because nodejs executes **data.save** before end of forEach loop

I use cursor to iterate over MongoDB find() function, but how can I iterate over array in the mongodb document, wait for it to complete the execution and then call **data.save**

Comment: hmm.. i don't see any documentation for the document returned to the callback of a call to findOne. Is that .forEach just Array.prototype.forEach? if it is... then i think you are mis-diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb find returns array so in your case data will be array and data.myarray will be undefined you can't execute data save too

Comment: sorry its a typo lets say we do Data.findOne({}) in place of Data.find({})

Comment: forEach isn't asynchronous it's blocking so data.save can't be executed before forEach finishes iteration, there is another issue, I noticed that you return player what is it?

Comment: yeah thats not happening here, data.save is not saving the data in DB (its not player return its data return only)